# Angular/Karma/Jasmine - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'commLogger.SetLogLevel')

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to learn Karma and Jasmine Unit Testing but I'm currently encountering an error here. I tried to research all of the answers in this site but came up with no answers.

Below is my unit test file.

```
describe('CommLogger', function() {
    var commLogger;

    beforeEach(module('FileLoggerManager'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (CommLogger) {
        commLogger = CommLogger;
    }));

    describe('SetLogLevel', function() {
       it('SetLogLevel Spec', function () {
            var logLevel = 0;
            commLogger.SetLogLevel(logLevel);
            expect(commLogger.SetLogLevel).toHaveBeenCalledWith(logLevel);
       });
    });
});
```

This is the the js file that I want to unit test.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('FileLoggerManager')
        .service('CommLogger', Body);

        function Body(LocalData, $q, $timeout) {
            var service = {
                writeLog: writeLog,
                SetFilePath: SetFilePath,
                SetMaxLogSize: SetMaxLogSize,
                DeleteLogFiles: DeleteLogFiles
            };

            var maxloglevel = 2;

            function SetLogLevel (logLevel) {
                console.log("Comm Logger: Set log level to " + logLevel);
                maxloglevel = logLevel;
            }

            return service;
        }
})();
```

I would gladly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have bootstrap error when `inject` runs, so the variable isn't assigned. There should be an error, but if there isn't, this may be because Phantomjs is known for swallowing errors. Try to switch to Chrome or move everything from `beforeEach` to `it` to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `CommLogger` service doesn't publicly expose the `SetLogLevel` function. Try adding it here:

```
var service = {
  ...
  SetLogLevel: SetLogLevel
};
```

Also, if you want to use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` you'll need to spy on the function:

```
describe('SetLogLevel', function() {
  it('SetLogLevel Spec', function () {
    spyOn(commLogger, 'SetLogLevel').and.callThrough();
    var logLevel = 0;
    commLogger.SetLogLevel(logLevel);
    expect(commLogger.SetLogLevel).toHaveBeenCalledWith(logLevel);
  });
});
```

See more information on [jasmine spies](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies).